# Jars generated by maven aren't executable (Main class not found)

Tags: java, maven, executable-jar

I have significant issues generating an executable jar with Maven.

First here is my project structure:

[image: Image of my IntelliJ Project structure]

Here is pom.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>scarlett.projects</groupId>
    <artifactId>FXTestApp</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>scarlett.Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjfx/javafx-controls -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>17</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjfx/javafx-graphics -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-graphics</artifactId>
            <version>17</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjfx/javafx-base -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-base</artifactId>
            <version>17</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjfx/javafx-fxml -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>17</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjfx/javafx-web -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-web</artifactId>
            <version>17</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjfx/javafx-swing -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-swing</artifactId>
            <version>17</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjfx/javafx-media -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-media</artifactId>
            <version>17</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjfx/javafx -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx</artifactId>
            <version>17</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Executing the project generates two jar files in the target directory:

```
FXTestApp-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
FXTestApp-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

The one I am interested in is the one with the dependencies. Unfortunately, executing this jar file generates an error:

[image: The error as seen in the shelll]
[image: First error when launched via double click]
[image: Second error when launched via double click]

Which translates into: Error: Mainclass [...] could not be found or loaded.

Looking inside the jar by changing it's ending from .jar to .zip shows an expected jar structure:

[image: The jar inside]

As expected, all the dependencies are there and my own source code too. The META-INF folder contains the MANIFEST.mf file which looks like this:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: Maven Archiver 3.5.0
Build-Jdk-Spec: 17
Main-Class: scarlett.Main
```

As can be seen the Main-Class is specified as desired.

Attempted solutions are using the Maven Shade plugin which resulted in the same outcome and including the Maven compile plugin. Additionally, I tried to follow various samples where a jar is built but also with no success. Also using the Maven jar plugin and no dependencies (just a simple `println("Hello World")` ) resulted in the same error.

@MadProgrammer pointed out that the command should be `java -jar FXTestApp-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar` instead. This results in a different error.

[image: different error]

My java updater says I am using the newest java version.

Comment: I strongly recommend to read the example documentation https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#maven (using javafx-maven-plugin) instead of maven-assembly-plugin....

Comment: Shouldn't the command be `java -jar FXTestApp-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar`?

Comment: @khmarbaise Thank you for your suggestion. Unfortunatly I already tried that and this resulted in the same error.

Comment: @MadProgrammer I tried your suggestion and got a different error message. Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: scarlett/Main has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 61.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file v
ersions up to 52.0 I have updated the question and tried to update my java version but it's up to date.

Comment: Your JAVA_HOME points to something different than what is in your `PATH`...

Comment: You need Java 17 (or later) in order to run the application.

Comment: @dan1st Thank you very much. I've set maven properties to 1.8 now it works. But I also tried to reinstall JRE and that din't help. Does that mean the JRE version lacks behind with version 1.8 ? (Thats the version the oracle installer installs https://www.java.com/en/download/manual.jsp)

Comment: Yes, the JRE needs to be at least 17 if you set source/target/release to 17. Oracle doesn't provide JREs any more in favor of runtime images from jlink/jpackage but note that JREs are included in JDKs.